# Cordova app unable to import 4000 contacts in iPhone

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, contacts

I am trying to import contacts using cordova contacts plugin in both Android and iOS. When there are 4000+ contacts, app is unable to find the contacts, same code working fine for Android and when there is few contacts. Even the plugin is not able to find the length of the contacts and not throwing any error in xcode console.

I am using "contacts.find" method to get the contacts from device. Is there any limitations for finding the contacts using cordova plugin?

Here is the code

```
function onDeviceReady() {

       filter = ["emails", "phoneNumbers"];

        // find contacts
        navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError);
    }

    function onSuccess(contacts) {
        for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
            alert(contacts[i].displayName);
        }
    };


    function onError(contactError) {
        alert('onError!');
    }
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: What the error, post your code, what is the plugin you are using and most import what is not working? You are just giving us to little to go on here,.

Comment: I am using cordova contact plugin and not getting error in console.

Comment: Don't just tell us you get an error, but post the error and relative code here.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, while importing a large number of contacts, its important to add the **ContactFindOptions** option to filter the required fields.

```
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter = "";
options.multiple = true;
options.desiredFields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName];
```

**desiredFields** must be added with required fields, it will help to skip the unnecessary fields to be imported from the huge data.